# How to run same tests on different servers using prove?

Tags: perl, unix, testing, perl-prove

I am using the Perl `prove` testing utility (TAP::Harness) to test my program.
I need to run the same tests first on a local computer, then on a remote computer.
(Test programs should connect to localhost or to remote host, respectively)

How can I pass parameters (test_server) to tests using prove? I should use environment or there is better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment variable sounds good, since you do not have easy access to higher abstraction means to pass data like command-line options or function parameters.

We already have prior art in the variables `TEST_VERBOSE`, `AUTOMATED_TESTING`, `RELEASE_TESTING` which influence how tests are run.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your larger goals, you may wish to approach the problem differently. We use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to control test suite runs that ultimately run "prove". It's set up to run tests on multiple servers and offers a number of features to manage "builds", which can be test suite runs.